# Can't refactor EntityManager in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, refactoring, entitymanager

I have a habit of getting into annoying bugs. I have checked forums but nothing seems to work. I accidentally dragged entitymanager (an invisible Swing component) and now I can't get rid of it. I tried the navigation tree to refactor but it throws this error:

References to selected elements were found. Remove all references to these elements in order to safely delete your class.

and it does not refactor at all. I seriously do not want to edit this file in notepad like some would suggest because I am sure there is a way to do it in Netbeans IDE. Any help appreciated :-)

Comment: post the screen shot of your application

Comment: Just resolved it. You can go to GUI form and then open the navigator and delete the element from there